# Get the value of a column based on min max values of another column of a pandas dataframe in a grouped aggregate function

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, group-by, aggregate

The pandas dataframe:

```
data = pd.DataFrame ({
    'group': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'],
    'date': ['2023-01-15', '2023-02-20', '2023-01-10', '2023-03-05', '2023-02-01', '2023-04-10'],
    'value': [10, 15, 5, 25, 8, 12]} )
```

Trying to get the values of the 'value' column based on the min and max values of 'date' column for each 'group' in an aggregate function:

```
## the following doesn't work
    output = (
      df
      .groupby(['group'],as_index=False).agg(
          ## there are some other additional aggregate functions happening here too.

          value_at_min = ('value' , lambda x: x.loc[x['date'].idxmin()])
        , value_at_max = ('value' , lambda x: x.loc[x['date'].idxmax()])
       ))
```

This doesn't work, even with converting date to datetime (in fact, my original date column is in datetime format).

Desired output should be:

```
    group   min_date    max_date    value_at_min    value_at_max
0   A       2023-01-15  2023-02-20      10              15
1   B       2023-01-10  2023-03-05      5               25
2   C       2023-02-01  2023-04-10      8               12
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort the dataframe by date then groupby and aggregate with `nth` to get the rows corresponding to min and max dates

```
g = data.sort_values(['date']).groupby('group')
g.nth(0).merge(g.nth(-1), on='group', suffixes=['_min', '_max'])
```

---

```
         date_min  value_min    date_max  value_max
group                                              
A      2023-01-15         10  2023-02-20         15
B      2023-01-10          5  2023-03-05         25
C      2023-02-01          8  2023-04-10         12
```

Comment: A very interesting solution. if i didn't want it in aggregate, i reckon this would be faster.

Comment: actually, i'll accept this as the answer as the other one didn't work due to computational time. This one was super fast too. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

As you mention the need for "additional aggregate functions", here's an approach that uses [`GroupBy.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

- For `value_at_min` and `value_at_max` retrieve `idxmin` and `idxmax` for column `date` and chain [`df.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html).

```
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'])

out = (data.groupby('group', as_index=False)
       .agg(
           # add other aggregations
           min_date=('date', min), 
           max_date=('date', max),
           value_at_min=('date', 'idxmin'), 
           value_at_max=('date', 'idxmax')
           )
       .replace({k: data['value'] for k in ['value_at_min','value_at_max']})
       )

out

  group   min_date   max_date  value_at_min  value_at_max
0     A 2023-01-15 2023-02-20            10            15
1     B 2023-01-10 2023-03-05             5            25
2     C 2023-02-01 2023-04-10             8            12
```

---

*Edit:* Performance being a concern with chaining `df.replace`, try [`df.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas.DataFrame.apply) and [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) instead. This should be much faster indeed:

```
out = (data.groupby('group', as_index=False)
       .agg(
           # add other aggregations
           min_date=('date', min), 
           max_date=('date', max),
           value_at_min=('date', 'idxmin'), 
           value_at_max=('date', 'idxmax')
           ))

out[['value_at_min','value_at_max']] = (out[['value_at_min','value_at_max']]
                                        .apply(lambda x: x.map(data['value']))
                                        )
```

Comment: I never thought of replace. Thank you! such a pretty solution.

Comment: It is sooooo very slow though for a large dataset. hmm.... Not sure if I can use it :(
already taking more than ten minutes for a small dataset (500K rows)

Comment: @Ankhnesmerira: added an alternative to `df.replace`, which should hopefully increase performance significantly, while still allowing you to add other aggregations. Interesting that `df.replace` gets so slow on a bigger `df`.

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to get this directly with `agg` as this method operates only on **one** column and you need two here. A hacky workaround would be possible using side-effects (referencing the dataframe using the index), but that's quite ugly and error prone.

Perform this aggregation independently of other aggregations, then join if needed.

So here, I would rather get the idxmin/max, then slice the original DataFrame:

```
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'])
tmp = data.groupby('group')['date'].agg(['idxmin', 'idxmax'])

out = (data.loc[tmp['idxmin']]
           .merge(data.loc[tmp['idxmax']],
                  on='group', suffixes=('_min', '_max'))
      )
```

With other aggregations:

```
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'])
g = data.groupby('group')['date']
tmp = g.agg(['idxmin', 'idxmax'])

out = (data.loc[tmp['idxmin']]
           .merge(data.loc[tmp['idxmax']],
                  on='group', suffixes=('_min', '_max'))
           # add your other aggregation functions here
           .merge(g.agg(...), on='group')
      )
```

Output:

```
  group    date_min  value_min    date_max  value_max
0     A  2023-01-15         10  2023-02-20         15
1     B  2023-01-10          5  2023-03-05         25
2     C  2023-02-01          8  2023-04-10         12
```

Another approach with a `pivot` (you can pick any number of rows):

```
out = (data
     .sort_values(by='date')
     .groupby('group', as_index=False)
     .apply(lambda g: g.iloc[[0, -1]])
     .assign(n=lambda g: g.groupby(level=0).cumcount())
     .pivot(index='group', columns=['n'])
)

d = {0: 'min', 1: 'max'}
out.columns = out.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{d[x[1]]}')

out.reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  group    date_min    date_max  value_min  value_max
0     A  2023-01-15  2023-02-20         10         15
1     B  2023-01-10  2023-03-05          5         25
2     C  2023-02-01  2023-04-10          8         12
```

Comment: This is very helpful. I can definitely use your pointers for other applications too. I think i was trying to do too much in aggregate and expect performance!

Answer (score 1):

get the minimum and maximum values, index the original dataframe to get the arrays, and finally create the new dataframe - it should be fast enough without having to sort, or merge:

```py
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'])
grp = data.groupby('group')
result = {"min_value": data.loc[grp.date.idxmin(), 'value'].array, 
          "max_value":data.loc[grp.date.idxmax(), 'value'].array,
          "min_date": grp.date.min().array,
          "max_date": grp.date.max().array,
         }
pd.DataFrame(result, index=grp.indices)

   min_value  max_value   min_date   max_date
A         10         15 2023-01-15 2023-02-20
B          5         25 2023-01-10 2023-03-05
C          8         12 2023-02-01 2023-04-10
```

Comment: this is a very nice looking solution... in fact, it is the closest thing to what I was looking/hoping for. Unfortunately its performance is worse than the chosen solution, yet much much better than using .replace.

Comment: Fair point. The accepted solution avoids aggregation and the merge is essentially a one to one join. The curious part for me is what is the slowest part of this code, the indexing or the aggregation? Anyways I appreciate the feedback

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame ({
    'group': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'],
    'date': pd.to_datetime(['1990-01-15', '1990-02-20', '1990-01-10', '1990-03-05',
                             '1990-02-01', '1990-04-10']), 

    'value': [10, 15, 5, 25, 8, 12]} )


df = data
res = df.groupby('group').agg(
    min_date = ('date','min'),
    max_date = ('date','max'),
    value_at_min = ('value',lambda d : d.iloc[0]),
    value_at_max = ('value',lambda d : d.iloc[-1])
    
    
    )
print(res)
"""        min_date   max_date  value_at_min  value_at_max
group                                                  
A     1990-01-15 1990-02-20            10            15
B     1990-01-10 1990-03-05             5            25
C     1990-02-01 1990-04-10             8            12
"""
```